# Is there a way to find the probability of different values in matrices

Tags: python, python-3.x, probability

I thought there would be a library that would help me to do this task instead of writing many lines of codes. I tried finding some solutions from books related to my problem, but I could not find any.

One of the recent books I did read related to probability:

> Python for Probability, Statistics, and Machine Learning for José
>   Unpingco

The task is that I have a matrix like this one below

```
0    1
213 vha
342 gha
523 xha
121 gha
812 gha
612 vha
123 gha
```

and I want the program to calculate the steps of moving from, say, `vha` to `gha` in the second row. and from `gha` to `xha` in the third row. If any step is repeated, it will be added to the previous step. For example `vha` to `gha` in the first and second rows is repeated at the end of the matrix.

The desired output is will be the `similar steps added together`/ `total number of rows-1`. In the first case it is `vha` to `gha` prob = 2/7-1

Desired output

```
vha to gha prob = 0.3
gha to xha prob = 0.16
xha to gha prob = 0.16
gha to gha prob = 0.16
gha to vha prob = 0.16

Total probs = 1
```

Comment: What datatype is this "matrix"?

Comment: it is `<class 'list'>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count how many times a transition occurs and then calculate probabilities for each transition.

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to combine two slices of the list `m` - one with the last element removed and another with the first element removed - to get tuples for adjacent elements. `zip(m[:-1], m[1:])` does that. Then can you can count similar tuples - which represent transitions - with a `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

m = [[213, 'vha'],
     [342, 'gha'],
     [523, 'xha'],
     [121, 'gha'],
     [812, 'gha'],
     [612, 'vha'],
     [123, 'gha']]

c = Counter([(x[1], y[1]) for x, y in zip(m[:-1], m[1:])])
probs = [(e, v / (len(m) - 1)) for e, v in c.items()]

for p in probs:
    print(p)
```

**Output**

```
(('vha', 'gha'), 0.3333333333333333)                                                                                                                
(('gha', 'xha'), 0.16666666666666666)                                                                                                               
(('xha', 'gha'), 0.16666666666666666)                                                                                                               
(('gha', 'gha'), 0.16666666666666666)                                                                                                               
(('gha', 'vha'), 0.16666666666666666)
```

Comment: Amazing! the code is working. I have accepted your answer.
I am just wondering if you can explain how the program works or refer me to a link with an explanation. Regards

Comment: @AbdulazizAlJumaia I've added links to documentation an a more detailed explanation. Hope that helps!

Comment: It does :). Thanks